# Fetching particular data from firestore using Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore as a database with my Flutter Application. I am storing data in the following way:

[image: My FFirestore Database Image]

I want to get data of shop based upon document ID(which is the id of currently logged in user). I am using following code but unable to fetch particular data.
And using stream builder for to display data.

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance
              .collection('Shops')
              .document(user.uid)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            print(snapshot.hasData);
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                        _buildRow(context, snapshot, i),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        _buildShopDetails(context, snapshot, i),
                        _buildReviewsRatingCard(snapshot, i),
                      ]),
                    );
                  });
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
```

So kindly help me in solving my problem.

Comment: Hello, why did you tag this question with the `google-cloud-functions`tag?

Comment: I think this is very well documented over internet. for example you can see [this](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-cloud-firestore-in-flutter-9ea80593ca40) article. As you don't specify how are you getting the user id I would recommend you to make a simple test just hard coding that value in your stream and print in the console the result to double check.